# How to make office-js MS Word Add-ins to work with Connected experiences disabled?

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

We have at team, who needs to have [Connected experiences in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/privacy/connected-experiences) disabled.

How can I get a office-js MS Word Add-in with a backend to work with Connected experiences disabled?

Comment: Have you tried at least running your Word add-in on a machine with Connected experiences in Office disabled?

Comment: yes, it doesn't work with Connected experiences disabled

Answer (score 2):

You may try to exclude Office add-ins from the list of disabled connected experiences. If you're an admin, these optional connected experiences can be managed by privacy controls for connected experiences or by the *Allow the use of additional optional connected experiences in Office* policy setting.